# What is the correct way of writing the log-odds in logistic regression?

Tags: probability, logistic, odds-ratio

The most sources I know write the log-odds as $log[Pr(y=1|x)/Pr(y=0|x)]$, where

$Pr(y=1|x) = \frac{e^{\beta^T x}}{1+e^{\beta^T x}}$,

which eventually allows me to write the log-odds as

$\log\frac{Pr(y=1| x)}{Pr(y=0| x)} = \beta^T x$.

However, sometimes I found the reverse defintion. For example in the [lecture notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guestrin/Class/10701-S07/Slides/logisticregression-decisiontrees.pdf) of the Carnegie Mellon University, they define

$Pr(y=0|x) = \frac{e^{\beta^T x}}{1+e^{\beta^T x}}$

And hence get another odds-ratio. Bascially, they just swap the definitions. How is this to understand?

Comment: maybe this will help (see ath the end, after EDIT): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168637/logistic-regression-what-happens-to-the-coefficients-when-we-switch-the-labels/168641#168641

Comment: This is easy to resolve when you consider that odds is always the odds *of some event*.  Conventionally we're interested in the odds of $Y = 1$ but there's no reason why we can't look at $Y = 0$ instead.

Comment: Ok - I see that. So basically it depends on what I want to look at. But isn't it a problem when I estimate the model for example in R? Since the default is y=1?

Comment: the result is the same, except that the signs of the coefficients switch (which is expected), see EDIT at the bottom of  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168637/logistic-regression-what-happens-to-the-coefficients-when-we-switch-the-labels/168641#168641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments, copied below:

This is easy to resolve when you consider that odds is always the odds of some event. Conventionally we're interested in the odds of Y=1
but there's no reason why we can't look at Y=0 instead. – dsaxton

the result is the same, except that the signs of the coefficients switch (which is expected), see EDIT at the bottom of [Logistic regression: what happens to the coefficients when we switch the labels (0/1) of the binary outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168637/logistic-regression-what-happens-to-the-coefficients-when-we-switch-the-labels/168641#168641)